# Why i got negative numbers in RGB?

Tags: python

I wanna to make my picture to split into rgb value. When i make 3d plot is shows that there is negative RGB value, altough it should be 0 value not negative. Why it can happened? Is there any solution?

this is the code

This is the 3dplot
[negative rgb values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TSFk.png)

this is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import cv2

#read image
img = cv2.imread('warna.jpg')



#convert from BGR to RGB
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

#get rgb values from image to 1D array
r, g, b = cv2.split(img)

print r
print g
print b
r = r.flatten()
g = g.flatten()
b = b.flatten()



#plotting 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(r, g, b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just as a notice: split() splits into b,g,r not r,g,b. Otherwise the rgb values can not be negative, there must be an error in another part of your code.

Comment: @WeGi is any possible if bgr has negative values?

Comment: @WeGi i convert bgr to rgb first, but the result is still be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the values are actually `0` and not negative, it just looks that way in the plot. Can you maybe print the `min` of `r` `g` and `b`?

Comment: how can i do this things?

Comment: `print min(r)` same for `g` and `b`

Comment: I think i already have the answer mate, in this link https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/39380-negative-values-of-pixels-in-aimage. So thats why my pixels have some negative values of pixels in an image.